# How do I create a series of measures in Power BI for each day of the week with multiple filters?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I would like to create a series of measures that shows my current week's sales by day. Example: 1 measure shows Sunday's sales, 1 measure shows Monday's sales, etc.

In order to identify the current week, I have added a field to my date table called 'Week Rank' in combination with the max function.

When I use the below formula, I get a very wrong answer. Trying to figure out what the figure is, but no luck so far. What is wrong with my formula?

Sunday Sales = calculate(sum('Transaction_Data'[TotalSales]),filter(all('Dates'), Dates[DayOfWeekName]="Sunday" || Dates[Week Rank]=MAX('Dates'[Week Rank])))

Comment: Doesn't it raising an error?

Comment: @Dani U Thank you soooo much! The formula works perfectly, and is well thought out. I definitely learned something new today. Will try to structure my formulas like this from now on. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will work, and will be very easy to copy-paste 6 more times. You just have to change the measure name and the value of the `this_day` variable.

I would like to point out that the REMOVEFILTERS statement is a replacement for the ALL statement in your version. In this scenario, they are interchangeable; however, REMOVEFILTERS offers more clarity and, IMO, should be used when ALL is being used for the purpose of eliminating filters.

```
Sunday Sales = 

var this_day = "Sunday"
var this_week = MAX(Dates[Week Rank])

RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM('Transaction_Data'[TotalSales]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(Dates),
    Dates[DayOfWeekName]= this_day,
    Dates[Week Rank] = this_week
)
```